# "last" operator for functions?

Tags: perl

Does Perl have an operator to exit a function or a `last` for functions?

```
sub f {

    # some code here

    if ($v == 10) {
    # goto end of function/exit function/last
    }

    # some code here
}
```

A `goto` could do the trick, but it seams wrong somehow?

Comment: Like in almost all programming languages- `return;` will exit functions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `return;` to exit a subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ... it is possible to use [`goto`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/goto.html) to go to the end of the subroutine:

```
sub f {

  # some code here

  if ($v == 10) {
    goto END;
  }

  # some code here
  END:
}
```

Or to use [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) to skip to the end of the subroutine ( if you add a block ):

```
sub f {
  END: {

    # some code here

    if ($v == 10) {
      last END;
    }

    # some code here

  } # END
}
```

What you really want to use is [`return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html)

```
sub f {

  # some code here

  if ($v == 10) {
    return;
  }

  # some code here

}
```

If you want to find out about what functions are available, I would checkout [the perlfunc manpage](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html).